# Concatenate multiple json objects present in the single data cell

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I have a column say **placeditems** where each time an user places his order a json object is stored.So, i'm able to display the first json object(first order) successfully.It throws an as *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()* for the second and forth objects.`

```
Collection {#207 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
  0 => Order {#211 ▼
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #fillable: array:8 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:10 [▶]
  #original: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "tableno" => "9"
    "noofitems" => 2
    "placeditems" => ""[{\"item\":\" Cafe Latte\",\"qty\":\"2\"}][{\"item\":\" Egg Sandwich\",\"qty\":\"3\"}]""
    "total" => 106
    "paidstatus" => 0
    "deliveredstatus" => 0
    "created_at" => "2017-07-14 11:32:29"
    "updated_at" => "2017-07-14 11:36:37"
    "username" => "harish"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

`
in laravel view blade

```
 @foreach($orders as $order)
      @foreach(json_decode($order->placeditems, true) as $item)
      <p>
          {{ $item['item'] }}
          <span>
          ( {{ $item['qty'] }} )
          </span>
      </p>
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Comment: how do you update the field for the second order?

Comment: Show the relevant code and data structure. Nobody is going to guess at why your code throws errors when they can't see it. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]